# How do you add auto-complete fonts to VSCode?

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-code

We'd like to add our apps' fonts to the auto-complete of vscode.
How do you add to this list?

[image: vscode autocomplete]

Comment: Interesting question. Maybe look into adding a snippet? [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets)

Comment: you can change the file `resources/app/extensions/css-language-features/server/dist/cssServerMain.js`. But you need to do it each time you update VSC

Comment: Making changes in `cssServerMain.js` don't seem to come through, even after a restart. Thought that might be good short term but definitely not a scalable solution. 